# Lego / certbot + DNS Challenge in a CNAME scenario

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot, acme

i am trying to create a certbot / lego ACME client, which can create letsencrypt certificates with the DNS plugin for Route53.
LetsEncrypt allows to "redirect" a domain to another provider with a CNAME.

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/
*Since Let’s Encrypt follows the DNS standards when looking up TXT records for DNS-01 validation, you can use CNAME records or NS records to delegate answering the challenge to other DNS zones. This can be used to delegate the _acme-challenge subdomain to a validation-specific server or zone. It can also be used if your DNS provider is slow to update, and you want to delegate to a quicker-updating server.*

But it looks like, certbot or Lego are not able to do this.

Lego has a CNAME Issue: https://github.com/go-acme/lego/issues/1580
Certbot has a CNAME Issue: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/7244

Does anyone has any tool, which supports CNAME?